# will statuses/followers twitter api fetch followers list from a 'Protect my Tweets' account?

Tags: twitter

The online explanation of 'Protect my Tweets' doesn't seem to restrict the ability to fetch follower list from an authorized user, but i got a 401 (Unauthorized) error when trying do that.

I'd like to confirm if this 'Protect my Tweets' will effect fetch follower list? If yes, is there any work around?

Besides, will it's alternative(followers/ids + users/lookup) has the same restriction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tweets and profile information, such as friends and followers, are withheld if a user has chosen to protect their tweets.  There's no "workaround" since this isn't a defect; it's by design.  If you want to get a protected user's tweets and relationships, then you must have your follow request accepted by the user with the protected account.

A protected user's Twitter page will display the following message that their profile and tweet data is unavailable.

> @protectedaccount's account is protected.  Only confirmed followers
>   have access to @protectedaccount's Tweets and complete profile. Click
>   the "Follow" button to send a follow request.

Finally, yes, `followers/ids` and `users/lookup` will be affected by this setting.

Comment: could you explain more about 'then you must have your follow request accepted by the user with the protected account'? how could i make them accept my follow request?

Comment: @Jia - If your account is protected, and you click on your *View my profile page* link, you will see a *Requests* section along with the usual Tweets, Following, Followers, etc.  Anyone that has requested to follow you must be followed back by you, so that gives you a single quick place to see anyone that you haven't followed back yet.  Alternatively, you can just follow the user back through any other method you like.